# Display events from last/next month's visible days in Calendar Month View

Tags: datetime

I'm using the [Calendar Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar) with the Month View to display events. My problem is that I need the last/next month´s visible days on each page of the calendar to also show their events instead of being grayed-out as shown in the image (Jan 29 to 31):

[image]

Has anybody solved this already?

Comment: Looking for this also